# If I change tabs and come back, my GIF freezes for a while (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, gif, p5.js, animated-gif

[Code for Catbus game](https://editor.p5js.org/petersenirs/sketches/DGKS_RAaF)

Whenever I try to run it, it works fine, but when I change to another tab and back, the gif freezes for the same amount of time I was in the other tab. I'm trying to be able to run both the background AND the gif. So, do y'all know anything that may fix the gif?

(Code is as follows)

```
let img;
let img2;
var bgImg;
var x1 = 0;
var x2;

var scrollSpeed = 4;

var screen = 0;
var y = -20;
var x = 200;
var speed = 2;
var score = 0;

let bing


function preload() {
  bgImg = loadImage("backgwound.png");

  bing=loadSound('catbus theme song.mp3')

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);

  img = loadImage("backgwound.png");

  img2 = loadImage("catgif.gif");

  x2 = width;

bing.loop()
  
}

function draw() {
  if (screen == 0) {
    startScreen();
  } else if (screen == 1) {
    gameOn();
  } else if (screen == 2) {
    endScreen();
  }

  let time = frameCount;

  image(img, 0 - time, 0);

  image(bgImg, x1, 2, width, height);
  image(bgImg, x2, 2, width, height);

  x1 -= scrollSpeed;
  x2 -= scrollSpeed;

  if (x1 <= -width) {
    x1 = width;
  }
  if (x2 <= -width) {
    x2 = width;
  }

  scale(0.4, 0.4);
  translate(300, 1855);

  image(img2, 0, 0);
}

function startScreen() {
  background(96, 157, 255);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("CAT BUS BIZARRE ADVENTURE", width / 2, height / 2);
  text("click any key to START", width / 2, height / 2 + 20);
  reset();
}

function gameOn() {
  background(0);
  text("SCORE = " + score, 30, 20);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(mouseX, height - 10, 50, 30);
  y += speed;
  if (y > height) {
    screen = 2;
  }
  if (y > height - 10 && x > mouseX - 20 && x < mouseX + 20) {
    y = -20;
    speed += 0.5;
    score += 1;
  }
  if (y == -20) {
    pickRandom();
  }
}

function pickRandom() {
  x = random(20, width - 20);
}

function endScreen() {
  background(150);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("GAME OVER", width / 2, height / 2);
  text("SCORE = " + score, width / 2, height / 2 + 20);
  text("click space to play again", width / 2, height / 2 + 40);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (screen == 0) {
    screen = 1;
  } else if (screen == 2) {
    screen = 0;
  }
}

function reset() {
  score = 0;
  speed = 2;
  y = -20;
}
```

Comment: A [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) is a very specific file format, not a generic term for something animated. You might want to fix your title / tags.

Comment: @ChrisG The issue is with the 6 frame cat GIF (actually a GIF file)

Comment: @Samathingamajig I looked at the GIF file, it is fine. It is set to loop forever.

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the route cause of the issue but I found a potential workaround, and it might even benefit you later when adding the ability for the cat to jump.

Rather than using `loadImage` I'm using `createImg` - here's a [link to the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createImg).

```
  let cat = {
    x: 50,
    y: 730
  }


  ...
  // in setup()

  catGif = createImg("catgif.gif");
  catGif.position(cat.x, cat.y);
  catGif.size(200, 100);
```

If you get stuck, I've implemented the changes in this [p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/petersenirs/sketches/DGKS_RAaF) to point you in the right direction.

Then later on, in your `draw()` method you can dynamically set the position of the cat based on some velocity, I'd recommend taking a look at [this post](https://codeheir.com/2020/09/12/how-to-code-flappy-bird-%f0%9f%90%a4/) as it should help you understand forces and how they can be applied to your game.

Comment: This creates a completely separate `<img>` DOM element. This would prevent anything on the canvas from appearing on top of the GIF. It would also prevent the GIF from being included in any images generated by `saveCanvas()`. It would also not work with any p5.js methods that work with `image()` such as `tint()`, `blend()`, or `imageMode()`.

Comment: @PaulWheeler yes to everything you said. However, not one of those methods would be needed to make the gif jump.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is actually a bug in p5.js. The code in [`_animateGif`](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/image/p5.Image.js#L227) that gets the current time is oddly buggy (sometimes it gets a time in the past). I don't understand why the authors of that code decided to use `pInst._lastFrameTime + pInst.deltaTime` instead of just using `pInst.millis()`.

Comment: GitHub Issue: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/5434